# Import .reg files from old HDD to the new one

Tags: windows-xp

Is there some way to import registry *(acces through "regedit")* to new HDD from the old one? i don't want to instal all the applications again, i've just move files from older "Program Files" to the new one.
**Thanks** to any answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You really do not want to do this.

The windows 7 registry is using an NT like structure, whereas XP isn't. Most keys will haven't changed, but some have, such as CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID where all the file ascociations are stored. This means that you will get in more trouble than what it gains.

You will need to convert the registry hive to do this. The best way to do this is by performing a windows 7 upgrade installation from XP.

Note that it will always be a lot slower to work with a converted XP install than to make a fresh windows 7 install and just install the programs again.

I estimate that all the trouble for converting XP to 7 will take more time than to reinstall the programs on a fresh 7 install.

Answer (score 0):

the `NTUSER.dat` is the user registry hive, you can load hives in regedit by clicking file->Load Hive.

(make sure HKLM or HKU is selected)

[image]

On the [Windows Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Windows_NT-based_operating_systems) article all registry locations are listed.

You can mount the corresponding hives you want:

```
Windows NT-based systems store the registry in a binary file format which can be exported, loaded and unloaded by the Registry Editor in these operating systems. The following system Registry files are stored in %SystemRoot%\System32\Config\:

Sam – HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SAM
Security – HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY
Software – HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE
System – HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM
Default – HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT
Userdiff – Not associated with a hive. Used only when upgrading operating systems.[29]
The following file is stored in each user's profile folder:

%UserProfile%\Ntuser.dat – HKEY_USERS\<User SID> (linked to by HKEY_CURRENT_USER)
For Windows 2000, Server 2003 and Windows XP, the following additional user-specific file is used for file associations and COM information:

%UserProfile%\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\Usrclass.dat (path is localized) – HKEY_USERS\<User SID>_Classes (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes)
For Windows Vista and later, the path was changed to:

%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Usrclass.dat (path is not localized) alias %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Usrclass.dat – HKEY_USERS\<User SID>_Classes (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes)
```

Comment: i am running WinXP SP3 on this notebook, and i see that option coloured grey, like it's unavailable :(
I should make screen but its in my language...
Anyway, thanks.

Comment: You need to select HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_USERS before you can import hives